# NVDA reads keys twice when typing into form fields

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

NVDA is reading the letters in a text input box twice, once when the key is pressed and again a half second later. When typing faster then only the last character is repeated. It is also reading the validation errors associated with the text box twice.

Answer (score 0):

The entire form was wrapped in aria-live="polite", an issue we have encountered at least three times now in our own projects, and simple as it is I thought it would benefit the community by being recording here.